# Possible to make Intel DC P3520 Series SSD's work with a Dell PowerEdge R720?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have 4 brand new Intel SSD's (DC P3520 Series) that I was told would work in our Dell PowerEdge R720 by a sales rep. Apparently he was wrong because the Dell is just not recognizing them even though they are a perfect fit and I have confirmed the connection to the backplane is good.

I called Dell and they said it's a firmware issue. However, these drives only physically interface into the server (SAS interface) so I can't use the server itself to try and update the firmware on the SSD's. Any ideas how I can make these work? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The P3520 drives you have purchased are NVMe drives, which means that although their interface looks like SAS, the protocol is not.

The reason your PERC cannot see them is because they are not talking a protocol that your PERC supports.

But what your sales rep told you is correct - sort of. If you purchased your R720 with "Express Flash", then those disks *will* work in the disk slots. I do not remember if Express Flash was standard or an option on the R720, so you'll need to check your configuration to see if you have any of those slots.

---

Update: Looks like its is an option on the R720, and it is only supported in the 8x2.5 disk models. It is an additional PCIe card that gets plugged in and connected to the backplane of the server, assuming the connections for 4 of the disks. [A kit like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Poweredge-R720-R820-PCIe-bridge-adapter-for-Express-Flash-NVME-PCIe-SSDs-86M4K-/131189604851) (I provide no guarantee that this will work in any way shape or form, if you choose to try this, it's at your own risk).

Comment: Excellent answer... and yes, the Sales rep did a poor job on this one.

Comment: Sadly the eBay listing specifically states that our server (16x 2.5" drive bays) isn't compatible with this, but thank you for all the great info!!

Comment: Link is dead. Mind updating?